# MS Access ODBC: Syntax error .. LIKE 'thomas%'

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

I am working on a mini application and I have to retrieve and save USER_ID in a table.

It works like this; I input the email address of the user and then the statement has to retrieve USER_ID and save it into a table.

I am having problem with my SQL Like statement.  Its just that I have to insert only the first part of the email address.  For example, "thomas@yahoo.com".  I insert only "thomas"; not remaining part.

Here are sample of the statement and resulting message I am getting in my Java console:

**Code:**

```
String ea = txt_email.getText();
String lid = "SELECT USER_ID FROM user WHERE email_address Like  '"+ea+"%' ";
```

**Error Message:**

> Error: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''SELECT USER_ID FROM user WHERE email_address Like  'thomas%' ''.

Comment: its not working friend...please show me another way :)

Comment: How are you invoking the SQL statement? Basic JDBC, Spring JDBC, Hibernate, ... ? The solution is likely to be different depending on the method.

Comment: @MithileshRamgolam Escape the JET reserved word in SQL. `select * from [User] where email ....`

Comment: @AVD "Use * instead of %" this is not true. Access uses both, depending on where you are working. In this case, % is right.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `*` instead of `%`. MS ACCESS uses `*` instead of `%` for the `LIKE` statement.

Hope this helps

Comment: If you could post the code section that leads up to the error

Comment: Whether Access uses * is % is complicated. For example, Access uses * when working in MS Access with DAO, it uses % when working with SQL Server compatible syntax and ADO. I reckon % is right in this case.

Answer (score 0):

use **[PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)**

```
PreparedStatement _query = con.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT USER_ID FROM user WHERE email_address Like ?");
_query.setString(1, ea + "*");  // <== use *
_query.executeQuery();
```

where `con` is your active connection object.

One advantage of using `PreparedStatement` is protect from `SQL Injection`

Comment: I think prepared statement is not an answer for this question, though it is good way for execution of the queries.